# Laravel | Edit all data from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

can you tell me how can I edit data from database's table - but no by ID.
I would like to do multiple editting data.

Now I have by id, and try to do something else.

Code:
list.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
    @foreach($metaList as $meta)
        <p class="card-text">{{ $meta->site_title }} </p>
    @endforeach
    <hr>
    <h5 class="card-title">Description</h5>         
    @foreach($metaList as $meta)
        <p class="card-text">{{ $meta->site_description }} </p>
    @endforeach
    <hr>
    <h5 class="card-title">Keywords</h5>
    @foreach($metaList as $meta)
        <p class="card-text">{{ $meta->site_keywords }}</p>
        <a class="card-link" href="{{ URL::to('meta/edit/' . $meta->id) }}"> 
        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>Edit</a>
        <a class="card-link" href="{{ URL::to('meta/delete/' . $meta->id ) }}" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fas fa-times"> 
        </i>Remove</a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And now I have multiple "edit" and "remove" buttons (as many rows as there are so many buttons).

I currently have a redirect to edit a specific ID.
How to create a redirect button to edit all rows at once?

MetaController:

```
public function edit(MetaRepository $metaRepo, $id)
    {
        $meta = $metaRepo->find($id);

        return view('pages.meta.edit', [
            "meta" => $meta,
        ]);
    }

    public function editStore(Request $request)
    {

        $meta = Meta::find($request->input('id'));
        $meta->site_keywords = $request->input('site_keywords');
        $meta->site_description = $request->input('site_description');
        $meta->site_title = $request->input('site_title');

        $meta->save();

        return redirect()->action('MetaController@mlist');
    }
```

and routing:

```
Route::get('meta/edit/{id}', 'MetaController@edit')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('meta/edit/', 'MetaController@editStore')->middleware('auth');
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mass update function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates) on Eloquent models.

```
Meta::update([
    'field1' => 'field1value', 
    'field2' => 'field2value'
]);
```

And if you only want to update certain rows, add a where function

```
Meta::where('field', '=', 'value')->update([
    'field1' => 'field1value', 
    'field2' => 'field2value'
]);
```

You will have to add the fields you want to use to the [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment) array in your model. Or set `$guarded` to `['*']`.

Comment: Okey, I understand, and what should the edit button look like in the view?